# Can I personalize the Metro background to be a custom image separate from the desktop image?

Tags: windows-8.1

Is there a way to do so? The only option I have so far is in the Personalize option in the Charms menu, and that allows me to pick the Desktop as the background for the start screen, but if I change the desktop background, so does the metro background. I'd like to have the Metro background be one image, and the desktop another.

Is there a tweak or hack to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several programs that you can find for this. One such program is [Decor8](http://www.stardock.com/products/decor8/), you can also check the [Customize the Windows 8 start and lock screen backgrounds with Decor8™!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46VITh_eHng)  video.

Comment: That costs money. If I get the trial, and uninstall, will it revert my settings back to Windows default?

Comment: Oh, I have not tried it. Since its a trail version there is every chance that the settings might get reverted. To overcome this you can take a backup of registry content and use it once you have uninstallled it.

PS: Consider this only if you have fully understand the registry process in the windows.